# Javascript Validation doesnt work in my Spring boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

As i try to do javascript validation but it dosent work on click of submit button

my Js Code : validation.js which is inside resource/static/js/validate.js

```
    function validate(){
var f=document.getElementById("form");

var hasEmailError = validateEmail(f);

if(!hasEmailError)
    return false;
    else
    return true;
    }

    function validateEmail(form){
    var error=document.getElementById("emailError");

    var email=form["email"].value;
    error.innerHTML="";
    var regx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|
    (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-
    Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if( email==null || email==""){
    error.innerHTML="Input Your Email";
    }

    else if(!email.match(regx)){
    error.innerHTML="Invalid Email";
    }
    if(error.innerHTML.length > 0)
    return false;
    else
    return true;
    }
```

my jsp code : registration.jsp

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="regUser" method="post" id="form">

First Name<input type="text" name="user_fname"><br>
Last Name<input type="text" name="user_lname"><br>
Email <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<font id="emailError" style="color: red;">${emailExistError} </font>
Contact No<input type="text" name="contactno"><br>
Password<input type="password" name="user_password"><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass@1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/hotelmgmt
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
server.port = 8090
```

pls tell where am i missing the point?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "it doesn't work"? What exactly doesn't work? What do you expect? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You need put `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validate.js"></script>` before close body tag instead of head tag.

Put this line in one line.

```
var regx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Current code show error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /"`

I tried reproduce your code, it worked

```js
  function validate(){
var f=document.getElementById("form");

var hasEmailError = validateEmail(f);

if(!hasEmailError)
    return false;
    else
    return true;
    }

    function validateEmail(form){
    var error=document.getElementById("emailError");

    var email=form["email"].value;
    error.innerHTML="";
    var regx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if( email==null || email==""){
    error.innerHTML="Input Your Email";
    }

    else if(!email.match(regx)){
    error.innerHTML="Invalid Email";
    }
    if(error.innerHTML.length > 0)
    return false;
    else
    return true;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<form action="regUser" method="post" id="form">

First Name<input type="text" name="user_fname"><br>
Last Name<input type="text" name="user_lname"><br>
Email <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<font id="emailError" style="color: red;"></font>
Contact No<input type="text" name="contactno"><br>
Password<input type="password" name="user_password"><br>
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Not me but I think the issue is just a typo :)

Comment: i did as what you said in jsp form as mentioned below 

`<body>
<form action="regUser" method="post" id="form">
Email <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<font id="emailError" style="color: red;"></font>
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validate.js"></script>
</body>`
and my validate.js file is in _src/main/resources/static/js/validate.js_

when i try to click submit button it dosent throw any message it directly redirect to next page without doing any validation.

Comment: did you try F12 and go to console tab, is there any error?

Comment: no error,  it directly redirect to next page i think jsp page not able to detect validate.js

Comment: did you try change src of script tag to /static/js/validate.js ?

Comment: your javascript code working perfectly  , but jsp page not able to detect validate.js page even after in correct path. is there anything else i need to add in jsp page so that my jsp page can detect validate.js

Comment: yes tried every possibility , but still js validaton not working, will review my code again , might be some problem in other part from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful for you to first simplify the return statements. 
The hasError =  !false is very confusing.